# PHP preg_replace certrain strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have several of these tags in a text document (stored in $content) with a lot of other content as well:

```
[[tag:author|id:6329]]
```

And I've been trying to replace all of these tags with a given id (in this case 6329) with another string.

```
$id = 6329;
$replacement = $this->format($id);
$pattern = "/(\[\[tag:author|id:".$id."\]\])/";
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Although this does not seem to work, and I've been tearing my hair out for the last couple of hours. Can anyone see the error? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape `|` too, and not necessary to wrap it with `()`.

Try:

```
$pattern = "/\[\[tag:author\|id:".$id."\]\]/";
```